# Do javascript has function where it send an alert/notification email to recipient within a given period?

Tags: javascript, jquery, phpmailer, php

I am new here and I have a question on javascript. Do javascript has function where it can automatic send an alert/notification email to recipient within a given period? For example, in the database, there is a "date" attribute. I want a javascript function to send an email automatically after 3 days starting from the "date" in the database..Thanks in advanced

Comment: Javascript doesnt have such a function. You can write a PHP script and execute it in a regular interval with via cronjob. E/ Or well, JavaScript can send mails. I would still recommend php for it.

Comment: javascript is a client-side code. You only can send a request to a (PHP) service in your server that perform sending of a mail if user visit your site (registred user because you need the mail).

Comment: Y U NO WORK is right. You may use CRON to check every 24 hours 'date' field and if 3 days past, send mail (PHP function mail). You don't need JavaScript, only PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, JavaScript (the way you are experiencing it) is a client-side language and cannot do what you want by itself. You will have to "ask" a server-side language to do that for you (note that JavaScript has a framework built on top of it that runs server-side, thanks @Cuberto)

Basically, you can do the scheduling in two ways:

**1)** Perform a countdown in the client browser, and when the timer hits 0 initiate a mail-sending request towards the server (very impractical, and sometimes outright impossible, as in your 3-day example).

**2)** Initiate a request immediately, and use cron or equivalent Windows service to do the scheduling for you (the "right", and much preferred, way).

Comment: This is wrong, you can run JavaScript on the server and send emails with Node.js

Comment: Not all hosting support node.js... it's not seems the way.

Comment: It's mentioned as an afterthought, to prevent labeling JavaScript as a client-side only language, not as a recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send an email directly with javascript.

You can use php or asp or something else that have server functionality.

Comment: you could have posted it as comment

Answer (score 0):

For sending emails JavaScript is not the right language. JavaScript is executed on the client side from where you cannot send emails (unless you use node.js). It also doesn't have access to the database which is on the server side.

What you are looking for is probably a PHP script to send emails. From php it is quite simple, just use the mail-function (http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mail.php).

For sending automatically after a period, you need to implement some logic. I'd implement a script that is executed regularily that checks whether it is time to send the email and after it has been sent, it will be marked as sent in the database, such that is it not send again.